# Unable to open Locknote on Windows 7 using Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby, winapi

I ran this code, and all it did was take me to the folder of the executable.  I had to click on the application exectable to open it.  Isn't this supposed to open automatically?

```
  require 'Win32API'
    def user32(name, param_types, return_value)
      Win32API.new 'user32', name,param_types, return_value
    end
    find_window = user32 'FindWindow', ['P', 'P'], 'L'
    system 'start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\locknote\LockNote 1.0.5"'
    sleep 0.2 while (main_window = find_window.call \
    nil, 'Steganos LockNote' ) <= 0
    puts "The main window's handle is #{main_window}."
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps`LockNote 1.0.5.exe` is the filename?